# Getting whole path recurvisely and non-recursively in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to append files to a list. But not just the files, but also the path to it,(ie, so it's not "abc.txt" but "/usr/home/USER/abc.txt")

I've spotted this online that gives me all recursive files

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):        
    for f in files:
        files_returned.append(f)
```

But what would be the correct way to get the full path, not just the filename? Would using root and f in files work?

Comment: Use `os.path.join(directory, f)` or `os.path.abspath(f)`.

Comment: Yes, it would. For each entry returned by `os.walk` iterate over `files`, and or each one do a `os.path.join(root, f)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `root` and [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):        
        for f in files:
            files_returned.append(os.path.join(root,f))
```